# Is there a way to detect if browser has been closed in a asp.net web mvc 5.0 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I am using tempdata for a variable and current have it set in the home controller and in my first last controller I have it removing that key by doing `if(TempData.ContainsKey())` `TempData.Remove()`. I placed that there assuming the user will go from point A to point D where D is the last controller. But I noticed if I close the application throughout any point of the application that the tempdata that was assigned i.e. `tempdata["username"] = username` will contain the previous value that was entered from the original start of the program and then will be updated after user enters a value to update the key for tempdata. **In a asp.net web mvc 5.0 project is there a way to check to see if a browser has been closed so that way I could remove the logic that is inside of the last controller that removes the key into the logic of checking if browser has been closed?**

Comment: This is probably not a great idea. There are many situations where this won't work properly, e.g. if there is a spotty network connection or if the user has two tabs open and closes one of them. Also, if you are actually storing user name, there are security implications, e.g. you are ripe for session fixation attack. A standard approach would be to leave whatever temp data there is but completely reset tempdata (and all other session variables) when the user first visits the site. This will have more or less the same effect from a user's perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the tab/browser being closed from javascript using the beforeunload event.  [Credited Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-browser-or-tab-closing-in-javascript/)

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // User is closing the tab/browser
    // You can cancel this event by using e.preventDefault();
    // and for older browsers by using  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

From there you can send a message back to your application using AJAX to handle the temp data removal.

Below using JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "AbandonSession",
    data: { someVar: "some val" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Session abandoned: " + msg );
});
```